# "Permission denied" when trying to link python using brew

Tags: python, macos

I have installed python using the below command on mac

```
    brew install python
```

And then when i try to link python using

```
    brew link python
```

I am getting this error

```
    "Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks"
```

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing this

```
  sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks
  sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local/Frameworks
```